# Unexpected Javascript Date object implicit conversion

Tags: javascript, date, implicit-conversion

Why Javascript's Date object returns different value for implicit conversions?

Number conversion:

```
+new Date()
// returns 1456293356618 as expected
```

String conversion:

```
''+new Date()
// returns "Wed Feb 24 2016 09:26:28 GMT+0" but "1456293356618" as a string was expected
```

Where can I find the documentation on ECMAScript and the implementation on v8's source?

Edit: I'm not looking for the solution for the expected result. I want to find the documentation in the specs.

Comment: `'' + (+new Date())` The ECMAScript spec is freely available online. (Why do you care about V8's source? It is just doing what *all* JS engines are supposed to do.)

Comment: @Rayon I didn't ask for the solution, I know how to get expected value. Please read the question again then down vote it if you wish

Comment: @nnnnnn your example doesn't explain *WHY* is ''+new Date not working as expected

Comment: Because the spec says to do that. Are you asking why the creators of the language/spec wanted it to work that way? I imagine the answer is that it makes sense to do it that way because normally you'd convert something to a string to let a user read it. But you can't do maths operations on a human-readable date string, so...

Comment: @nnnnnn I've read the specs, maybe I couldn't find it and i'm asking here, it would be nice if you share it here instead of down voting

Comment: I didn't down-vote. And I think my last comment gave a reasonable explanation why dates cast to strings in a format that is human-readable. The spec itself just gives the rules, it doesn't really explain *why* the rules are as they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+` operator is overloaded. In:

```
+new Date()
```

it is treated as the [*unary + operator*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-unary-plus-operator) and coerces the value to Number. In:

```
'' + new Date() // note one value is a string
```

it is treated as the [*string concatenation operator*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus) and coerces the values to String. In:

```
5 + 6   // note both values are number
```

it is treated as the [*addition operator*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus). Since the values are numbers, no coercion is necessary.

Note that whether `+` does addition or concatenation depends on the values and is described in [*ECMAScript 2015 §12.7.3.1 step 11*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus-runtime-semantics-evaluation).

Comment: Thank you, that wasn't very obvious to find.

Comment: Now I can use https://github.com/kushal-likhi/operator-overloading-js to mock this operator.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are refering to this [**Overview of Date Objects and Definitions of Abstract Operators**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-overview-of-date-objects-and-definitions-of-abstract-operations), specifically Section 20.3.1.1

> A Date object contains a Number indicating a particular instant in time to within a millisecond. Such a Number is called a time value. A time value may also be NaN, indicating that the Date object does not represent a specific instant of time.

This means that using math operations on a Date object will extract its Number value to work. That's why statements like `+new Date()` and `Math.floor(new Date())` returns a Number.

As for `'' + new Date()`, the Date object returns its String value perhaps using its `toString()` function.

Comment: Thank you, but I still can't find any mention of using toString instead of valueOf in the specs describing `'' + new Date()` behavior!

Comment: Note that the reference is to ES5, which is OK as the behaviour hasn't changed but it's not the latest version of ECMA-262. The reference for whether `+` does addition or concatenation is the same place in the spec ["*The addition operator either performs string concatenation or numeric addition.*"](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus).